# How to use Google Test to test a function which will call another function containing output parameters?

Tags: unit-testing, googletest

```
// Filter.h/cpp
class Filter
{
public:
    int readInt(int* value)
    {
        if (value == NULL)
            return 0;

        *value = 15; // some logical;
        return 1;
    }
};


// TestTee.h/.cpp
class TestTee
{
public:
  Func1(Filter* f)
  {
      ...
      int val;
      f->readInt(&val);
      ...
  }
}
```

Now, I need to test TestTee class, so I mock the class Filter

```
class MockFilter : public Filter
{
public:
    MOCK_METHOD1(readInt, int(int*));
};
```

how to write the test case?

```
TEST_F(TestClass, Test1)
{
    TestTee t;
    MockFilter filter;

    EXPECT_CALL(filter, readInt(_)).Times(1);  //  failed error:     The mock function has no default action set, and its return type has no default value set." thrown in the test body.
    /* 
    int val;
    EXPECT_CALL(filter, readInt(&val)).Times(1); 

    Failed with the following error:
          Expected: to be called once
          Actual: never called - unsatisfied and active
    */
    t.Func1(&filter);
}
```

So, my problem is

I don't know how to control the output parameters of a function which will be called in my testee function code.

Any comment? thx a lot.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, don't forget that a function needs to be virtual for GoogleMock to be able to actually mock it:

```
class Filter
{
public:
    virtual int readInt(int* value)
    {
        if (value == NULL)
            return 0;

        *value = 15; // some logical;
        return 1;
    }
};
```

The testing code depends on what you actually want to test. If you want just to ensure that Filter::readInt is called this should be enough:

```
TEST_F(TestClass, Test1)
{
    TestTee t;
    MockFilter filter;

    EXPECT_CALL(filter, readInt(_));

    t.Func1(&filter);
}
```

(Since readInt has built-in return type (int) GoogleMock should be able to figure out default return value without complaining)

If you want to ensure that readInt is called for example only once, use Times clause:

```
EXPECT_CALL(filter, readInt(_)).Times(1);
```

If you want the code of Testee following the readInt call to get adequate return values during test, i.e. if you want a mock to imitate returning values of real function, use Return clause for return value, and SetArgPointee clause for output value passed by pointer, or both like this:

```
EXPECT_CALL(filter, readInt(_)).WillOnce(DoAll(SetArgPointee<0>(15), Return(1)));
```